# How to create dynamic element in a dynamic form

Tags: javascript, html

this is my code for first element, inside of first  dynamic form

```
<input type="text" class=" form-control" id="pPilihan" style="font-size: 1rem;" name="p_pilihan[]" required placeholder="Masukan Nama Pilihan, contoh: Merah / XL">
```

Tambah

this is my code for add input element

```
<div class="copy d-none">
    <div class="control-group input-group" style="margin-top:10px">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="pPilihan" style="font-size: 1rem;" name="p_pilihan[]" required placeholder="Masukan Nama Pilihan, contoh: Merah / XL">
        <div class="input-group-btn"> 
            <button class="btn btn-danger remove" type="button"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></i> Hapus</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and this is my js

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("body").on("click", ".add-more", function(){ 
        var html = $(".copy").html();
        $(".after-add-more").before(html);
    });

    $("body").on("click",".remove",function(){ 
        $(this).parents(".control-group").remove();
    });
});
```

Comment: What's not working? You haven't explained your code or what the problem is.

Comment: Please edit and give more information.

Comment: just wait the second, i want to upload my image

Comment: please check my image, thanks before

https://ibb.co/dpcObV
https://ibb.co/e41Vqq
https://ibb.co/gAsQOA
https://ibb.co/fepTbV
https://ibb.co/h1oziA
https://ibb.co/cungwV

Comment: the simple is i want to make like this

https://ibb.co/mM3obV

Comment: i have fixed it,

i change my js like this,

<script type="text/javascript">
          $(document).ready(function() {
            $("body").on("click", ".add-more", function(){ 
          var html = $(".copy").html();
          $(this).before(html);
        });
            $("body").on("click",".remove",function(){ 
                $(this).parents(".control-group").remove();
            });
          });
      </script>

thanks before for your attention

Answer (score 1):

The question is not clear to me but I can see a bug in your code, you simply can't have two elements having the same id. Each time 'add more' button is clicked the input element with id="pPilihan" is getting repeated, which is wrong. You can solve this by using a counter to produce a dynamic id (if you need one).

Comment: please check my image, thanks before..

https://ibb.co/dpcObV
https://ibb.co/e41Vqq
https://ibb.co/gAsQOA
https://ibb.co/fepTbV
https://ibb.co/h1oziA
https://ibb.co/cungwV

Comment: i have fixed it,

i change my js like this,

<script type="text/javascript">
          $(document).ready(function() {
            $("body").on("click", ".add-more", function(){ 
          var html = $(".copy").html();
          $(this).before(html);
        });
            $("body").on("click",".remove",function(){ 
                $(this).parents(".control-group").remove();
            });
          });
      </script>

thanks before for your attention